# How can I extract user email address from User explorer in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-filters

When I visit the User Explorer section, I can find my user activity.

I want to know if there is a way by which I can get user information like email id. First of all is that possible? If it is possible then please guide for the same.

Thanks in Advance
Masum

Comment: Google services doesnt allow you to store PII but here you have a great way around it http://dmitriilin.com/encrypt-personally-identifiable-information-using-google-tag-manager/

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible. Google Analytics does not store personally identifiable information (PII) like names, addresses, e-mail addresses etc.

Google's terms of service specifically prohibit you from storing PII and Google reserves the right to terminate your account if you do.

Also you cannot query the user explorer report via the API, you'd need to store an (anonymized, non-PII) identifier for unique users as custom dimensions to extract data on a per-user basis.